# How can I access the machine or the device's date format from within an Ionic/cordova/angular mobile app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, mobile, ionic-framework

I am writing a mobile app with angular 1.x and ionic v1 w/ cordova.

I want to display a date on a view template.

I  have seen this library: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/
And I see that I can use 'L' to get the localized date/time format.
e.g moment().format('L').

I want my app to match the device system settings rather than the locale settings or the browser settings.

For example, if my Android phone shows the date in this format dd/mm/yyyy I want my app to match this.

How can I get the date/time format provided by the system?

Comment: Send it as a string from the server (in its timezone), dont use UTC and ISO standards if you are going to ignore them on the client.

Comment: Browser *Date* implementations tend to totally ignore system settings (other than timezone), so you can't use the built-in object to detect them in any meaningful or reliable way. The best you can do is use an unambiguous format, which is what the built-in *Date.prototype.toString* does, but it may not be in a format that you or your users prefer.

Comment: BTW, `moment().format('L')` is not "localised" in any meaningful way either, it's just mm/dd/yyyy, which might be "local" for people from the USA, but not elsewhere.